# Trigger compactions when TWCS TTL changes in Cassandra 3.0

Tags: cassandra

I have a table in cassandra where I saved data using clients TTL = 1 month (tables TTL is 0), the table is configured with time window compaction strategy.

Everyday Cassandra cleaned one single sstable containing expired data from one month ago. 
Recently I changed the clients TTL to 15 days, I was expecting cassandra to clean two sstables a day at some point, and release the space. But it keeps cleaning one sstable a day and keeping 15 days of dead data.

How do I know?

```
for f in /data/cassandra/data/keyspace/table-*/*Data.db; do meta=$(sudo sstablemetadata $f); echo -e "Max:" $(date --date=@$(echo "$meta" | grep Maximum\ time | cut -d" " -f3| cut -c 1-10) '+%m/%d/%Y') "Min:" $(date --date=@$(echo "$meta" | grep Minimum\ time | cut -d" " -f3| cut -c 1-10) '+%m/%d/%Y') $(echo "$meta" | grep droppable) ' \t ' $(ls -lh $f | awk '{print $5" "$6" "$7" "$8" "$9}'); done | sort
```

This command list all the sstables

```
Max: 05/19/2018 Min: 05/18/2018 Estimated droppable tombstones: 0.9876591095477787        84G May 21 02:59 /data/cassandra/data/pcc/data_history-c46a3220980211e7991e7d12377f9342/mc-218473-big-Data.db
Max: 05/20/2018 Min: 05/19/2018 Estimated droppable tombstones: 0.9875830312750179        84G May 22 15:25 /data/cassandra/data/pcc/data_history-c46a3220980211e7991e7d12377f9342/mc-221915-big-Data.db
Max: 05/21/2018 Min: 05/20/2018 Estimated droppable tombstones: 0.9876636061230402        85G May 23 13:56 /data/cassandra/data/pcc/data_history-c46a3220980211e7991e7d12377f9342/mc-224302-big-Data.db
...
```

For now I have been triggering the compactions manually using JMX, but I want all erased as it would normally do.

```
run -b org.apache.cassandra.db:type=CompactionManager forceUserDefinedCompaction /data/cassandra/data/keyspace/sstable_path
```

Comment: what is `gc_grace_period` on your tables? when did you change the TTL to 15 days?

Comment: @AlexOtt It's 86400 seconds (24 hours) and I changed it more than a month ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. Had to run manual compaction on the oldest and newest sstable with all it's content expired, both sstables at the same time. 
After a couple of days it cleanead everything.

How do I know it was running? Because when I tried to run forceUserDefinedCompaction on any other sstable in between it always returned null.

EDIT:
It didn't work, again Sstable count keeps increasing.

EDIT:
Using sstableexpiredblockers pointed to the sstables blocking the rest of compactions. After compacting these manually it automatically compacted the rest.

On one node out of 8, the blocking sstable wasn't been unlocked after compacting, so a "nodetool scrub" did the job (which scrubs all the sstables).